# What does [ -t 1 ] check?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, test

I just found a way to start `zsh` when I start the `bash` on Windows from

https://www.howtogeek.com/258518/how-to-use-zsh-or-another-shell-in-windows-10/.

It recommended to add following code at the last of `.bashrc`.

```bsh
# Launch Zsh
if [ -t 1 ]; then
exec zsh
fi
```

What does `[ -t 1 ]` mean?

Is it just true?

Then, can I just do this?

```bsh
exec zsh
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`[]` is shortcut of `test` command.

**According to `man test`:**

> -t FD
>       True if FD is a file descriptor that is associated with a terminal.

So if you running bash as interactive shell (terminal - see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) thread for terminology explanation), bash will be replaced by zsh.

**More about .bash* files:**

> When  bash  is  invoked as an **interactive login shell**, or as a
>   **non-interactive shell with the --login option**, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when 
>   the  shell  is  started  to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a **login shell exits**, bash reads and executes commands from the
>   files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists.
>
> When  an  **interactive  shell that is not a login shell** is started,
>   bash reads and executes commands from **~/.bashrc**, if that file exists. 
>   This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file
>   option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

**Stéphane Chazelas comment:**
Note that a shell can be interactive without stdout being a terminal, and a shell can be non-interactive with a terminal on stdout (like anytime you run a script within a terminal without redirecting/piping its output), and `bash` can read `.bashrc` even when not interactive (like in `ssh host cmd` where `bash` is the login shell of the user on host, or `bash --login -c 'some code'`). `case $- in *i*)...` is the correct way to test if a shell is interactive.

Comment: Note that a shell can be interactive without stdout being a terminal, and a shell can be non-interactive with a terminal on stdout (like anytime you run a script within a terminal without redirecting/piping its output), and `bash` can read  `.bashrc` even when not interactive (like in `ssh host cmd` where `bash` is the login shell of the user on host, or `bash --login -c 'some code'` where the `.bash_profile` sources the `.bashrc`). `case $- in *i*)...` is the correct way to test if a shell is interactive.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point. I will contain your comment in answer

Comment: There are a number of different definitions of "interactive". If the shell _thinks_ it is interactive, then `i` will be set (and in modern shells that can be tested with `if` instead of having to use `case`). But there are many use cases where one only cares if stdout (or stdin, or stderr...) is attached to a terminal.

Answer (score 15):

The [test command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) `[ -t 1 ]` checks whether bash's output is on a terminal. The intent of this line is clearly to run zsh when opening a terminal, without disrupting other uses of bash. But it's done very badly.

The file `.bashrc` is read in three circumstances:

- When bash is executed as an interactive shell, i.e. to run commands typed by the user rather than to execute batch commands.
- When bash is a *non-interactive* shell which is run by an RSH or SSH daemon (typically because you run `ssh host.example.com somecommand` and bash is your login shell on `host.example.com`).
- When it's invoked explicitly, e.g. in a user's `.bash_profile` ([bash's choice of startup files is a bit weird](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work/88149#88149)).

`[ -t 1 ]` is a poor way to detect interactive shells. It's possible, but rare, to run bash interactively with standard output not going to a terminal. It's more common to have standard output going to a terminal in a non-interactive shell; a non-interactive shell has no business running `.bashrc` but unfortunately bash shells invoked by SSH do. There's a much better way: bash (and any other sh-style shell) provides a built-in, reliable method to do it.

```
case $- in
  *i*) echo this shell is interactive;;
  *) echo this shell is not interactive;;
esac
```

So “launch zsh if this is an interactive shell” should be written

```
case $- in
  *i*) exec zsh;;
esac
```

But even that is not a good idea: it prevents opening a bash shell, which is useful even if you use zsh. Forget about this blog post and instead simply configure your shortcut that opens a terminal to run zsh instead of bash. Don't arrange things so that “whenever you open the Bash application on Windows, it will now start up with the Zsh shell”: when you want zsh, open the Zsh application.

Comment: For  `rsh`/`ssh` and for interactive shell, it's if it's **not** a login shell. For login shells (`sshd` would not start a non-interactive login shell, but you could do it with `ssh host exec bash -l`), `.bash_profile` is read instead. Also note that for `rsh`/`ssh`, you also need `$SHLVL` to be unset or 0.

Comment: I suggest to use `[[ -x /usr/bin/zsh && $- = *i* ]] && exec /usr/bin/zsh` instead as it will checks first if `zsh` is installed (actually if there is executable`/usr/bin/zsh`) then so switch to `zsh` otherwise we will fail to login to bash terminal if that's not installed.

Answer (score 6):

[man 1 test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> -t FD
>
> file descriptor FD is opened on a terminal

Your example executes (replaces running process, in this case `bash`) with `zsh` on if *stdout* is open on a terminal (not a file/pipe/etc).