# Why does Bash behave differently when compiled from source code?

Tags: bash, source-code

I ran

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/bash.git
cd bash/
./configure
make
./bash
```

I noticed that the newly launched Bash instance did not inherit the environment, specifically the PS1 variable that defines the shell prompt, from the parent shell.
The inheritance works for `/bin/bash`

[List of sourced files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029490/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-all-files-that-are-sourced-by-bash) is the same for `/bin/bash` and `./bash`

```
./bash  -lixc exit 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^+* \(source\|\.\) //p'
/bin/bash  -lixc exit 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^+* \(source\|\.\) //p'
```

Edit:
As aviro mentiond PS1 was defined without export, so when I tried exporting it got inherited, so my initial question was wrong.
On my machine PS1 is defined in two files
`/etc/bash/bashrc`

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
[[ $DISPLAY ]] && shopt -s checkwinsize
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

And `/etc/bash/bashrc.d/artix.bashrc`

```
if ${use_color} ; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='\[\033[01;31m\][\h\[\033[01;36m\] \W\[\033[01;31m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='\[\033[01;36m\][\u@\h\[\033[01;37m\] \W\[\033[01;36m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi
else
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        # show root@ when we don't have colors
        PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '
    else
        PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
    fi
fi
```

When I ran `./bash` the PS1 is `\s-\v\$` and I have no idea why.

The command listing all sourced file shows that both of these files should be sourced when run with `./bash`, but for some reason they aren't or shell starts in different type/mode. Why?

Comment: `PS1` is not an environment variable - it's a shell variable. Those variables are not inherited from the parent. They are read from the `profile` / `bashrc` files every time a new shell starts. The question is if you changed the `PS1` variable in the parent, or if it comes from one of your  `profile` / `bashrc`  files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What value of `PS1` do you see, what value do you expect? Do you set the variable in a file like `.bashrc`? Does the problem not occur if you start `/bin/bash` instead of `./bash`?

Comment: @aviro [Shell Command Language section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) states: _"Variables shall be initialized from the environment ..."_ and lists `PS1` as one of the Shell Variables.

Comment: @Vilinkameni Yes, If there is an **environment variable** it would be used instead of the shell variable. So, for instance, if you run `export PS1=...`, now `PS1` will be an environment variable and children `bash` instances will inherit it.  But if you just run `PS1=...` (without `export`), it will be shell variable and children `bash` processes won't inherit it.

Comment: @aviro So they **are** "inherited from the parent" - if they are `export`ed in the parent.

Comment: @Vilinkameni The point is `PS1` is usually (and possibly in the OP's case) not exported.

Comment: Merely invoking bash as `./bash` or `/bin/bash` will make it run the commands in `bashrc`, but not `profile` because it's not a login shell.

Comment: `PS1` is especially odd in that Bash explicitly clears it if running non-interactively. If nothing else, that's one reason to set it in `bashrc`, and it might even be unconditionally set, making it rather hard to inherit the prompt from the environment. But if `bashrc` doesn't set it, and you run an interactive shell, it will get inherited as usual. That can be useful if you want to run a shell in some unusual environment and feed it a prompt to remind yourself of that. But you need to make sure your startup files support that.

Comment: If you want to test if the vars get inherited from the environment, run something like `PS1=inherited XYZ=inherited ./bash` and see what the prompt looks like and what `echo "PS1=$PS1" "XYZ=$XYZ"` print. Same for the other Bash.

Comment: @Bodo I said that "The inheritance works for `/bin/bash`" so the problem doesn't occur, but my initial guess was wrong, it is not related to inheritance.

Comment: that command where you read the output of `bash -lix` doesn't tell all files it reads. It tells the `.` or `source` commands it executes. If you look at the list it outputs, it's missing `/etc/profile` or `.profile`, even though Bash does read them for a login shell. And similarly when run without the `-l` option, the list is missing `~/.bashrc`. That is, it doesn't tell the files it runs by itself, meaning it doesn't tell the options it was compiled with.

Comment: Try running e.g. `strings ./bash |grep bashrc` and compare with the other binary. Or put something in `/etc/bash/bashrc` you can use to tell if it was actually read, perhaps something like `echo this is /etc/bash/bashrc` or whatever. Just be sure to remove it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to understand that `PS1` is usually a
[shell variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference), which means it isn't inherited by the children. So unless you explicitly ran `export PS1=...` and made `PS1` an environment variable, every new `bash` process will get the `PS1` (and other shell variables) from the rc files and not from the parent. So you first need to find out where exactly your `PS1` is defined.

You can verify that by exporting your `PS1`:

```
export PS1
```

And then run your `./bash`. You'll see that in that case, `PS1` will be inherited by the new shell.

---

So why doesn't your compiled `bash` get the `PS1` shell variable you expect from the rc files?

Here's my guess: On many systems, `PS1` is being defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. But not all `bash` versions read this file. It depends on how `bash` was being compiled. A good rule of thumb would be checking your `bash` man pages. For instance, for [Ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html) you'll see:

> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started,
> bash reads and executes commands from **`/etc/bash.bashrc`** and `~/.bashrc`,
> if these files exist.  This may be inhibited by  using the `--norc`
> option.  The `--rcfile` file option will force bash to read and execute
> commands from file instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

However, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is not even mentioned in the [`bash` man page](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/bash.html) you downloaded from that [git]:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
> reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists. This
> may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option. The `--rcfile` file option
> will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
> `~/.bashrc`.

Additionally, in the [`README`](https://sources.debian.org/src/bash/5.2.15-2/debian/README/) file of `bash` from Debian, you'll see:

> 5. What is `/etc/bash.bashrc`? It doesn't seem to be documented.
>
> The Debian version of bash is compiled with a special option
> (`-DSYS_BASHRC`) that makes `bash` read `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc`

So in the `git` repository you've used, you'll see at
[`config-top.h`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git;a=blob_plain;f=config-top.h) that the line that defines `SYS_BASHRC` is commented out by default.

```
/* System-wide .bashrc file for interactive shells. */
/* #define SYS_BASHRC "/etc/bash.bashrc" */
```

So your `bash` as it's built by default won't read `/etc/bash.bashrc` on startup, and if your `PS1` is defined there, it won't get it.

If you remove the comment from this line:

```
#define SYS_BASHRC "/etc/bash.bashrc"
```

and run `make` again, my guess is that your new `bash` will show the `PS1` variable you expect.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247627/367454 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=141193 (example)

Comment: Thanks, the only question remaining is why the command listing all sourced files shows that `/etc/bash/bashrc` is being source when it isn't, I haven't spend much time analyzing this command.

Comment: @Rustacean your command is faulty. It lists explicit `source` commands, but of course misses the files that bash reads initially, and also files sourced using `.`. Try something like: `PS4=' source:${BASH_SOURCE[0]@Q} ' /bin/bash -lixc exit 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -Po '^ *source:\S*' | awk
'!seen[$0]++'`

Comment: The file that sets PS1 is listed by my command, but for some reason it isn't sourced, that's my problem.

Comment: @Rustacean you **assume** that that's the file that sets your `PS1`. As repeatedly mentioned, not ALL the files that are being sourced will appear in your list. There might be different files that don't appear in your list. Also, maybe the file you assume doesn't even get to the line you mentioned due to some condition. Based on the command that @muru suggested, please run the following to actually see where your `PS1` is defined at: : `PS4=' source:${BASH_SOURCE[0]@Q} ' /bin/bash -lixc exit 2>&1 >/dev/null  |grep PS1`

Comment: It seems that @Rustacean is using Artix Linux. In its custom [_system.bashrc_](https://gitea.artixlinux.org/packages/bash/src/commit/9f307f3382ecb1fb3110506c3a6d13ccf54b1e8b/system.bashrc#L22) ([copied](https://gitea.artixlinux.org/packages/bash/src/commit/9f307f3382ecb1fb3110506c3a6d13ccf54b1e8b/PKGBUILD#L74) to _/etc/bash/bashrc_), there is a loop sourcing all files under _/etc/bashrc.d_ in a manner like modprobe and similar tools. (continues)

Comment: (continued) The [`build` function](https://gitea.artixlinux.org/packages/bash/src/commit/9f307f3382ecb1fb3110506c3a6d13ccf54b1e8b/PKGBUILD#L45) contains all the parameters passed to the build process of Bash for Artix Linux.

Comment: @Rustacean There is a number of ways you can debug what happens during the startup of your custom-built Bash. Inside all of the relevant files, you can redirect output to some file, print to stderr, or even use [logger(1)](https://www.mankier.com/1/logger). Not that there may be more custom-set things in a particular package for a particular distro, which you can only know when looking at that packages' source files.

Comment: @aviro I've tested by adding simple echo command at the start of the file that sets PS1 and I didn't get any output, so the file isn't sourced at all, I might run that PS4 command later. I would like to remind you that my problem is not about PS1, it's about the list of sourced files and why the list is wrong that's it.

Comment: @Vilinkameni I'm building bash from source, so distro I'm using doesn't really matter, because I haven't use build function you provided, I'll eventually use that build function when I'm done modifying bash code.

Comment: Part of the functionality expected from Bash (specifically, related to `PS1`) in your distro comes from the scripts provided by maintainers, so it does matter. If you configure Bash in a different manner than the one specified in _PKGBUILD_, it might not work as expected.

Comment: Just one example: `-DNON_INTERACTIVE_LOGIN_SHELLS`; from the file _NEWS_ in the main source directory: _"v.  If NON_INTERACTIVE_LOGIN_SHELLS is defined, all login shells read the startup files, even if they are not interactive."_

Comment: @Rustacean the command with `PS4` will help you find where `PS1` is defined. Check the meaning of `PS4` in the man pages of `bash`, and you'll understand how it might help.